# Show that if $\epsilon\to0$ then $(1/\alpha(\epsilon))\int_{\partial B_\epsilon(0)}\varphi(x) d\sigma =\varphi(0)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove that for a function $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\alpha(\epsilon)$, the surface of the ball $B_\epsilon (0)$
\begin{align*}\underset{\epsilon\to0}{\lim} (1/\alpha(\epsilon))\int_{\partial B_\epsilon(0)}\varphi(x) d\sigma =\varphi(0). \end{align*}

At some point, it's necessary using the fact that $\varphi$ is continuous. I was thinking about rewriting $\alpha(\epsilon)$ like an integral but I don't achieve anything with it. Please, ¿can you give me some hint?

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track with $\alpha(\epsilon)$ as an integral: Rewrite
$$
\left| \dfrac{1}{\alpha(\epsilon)}\int_{\partial B_\epsilon(0)} \varphi(x)\, dx - \varphi(0)\right| = \left| \dfrac{1}{\alpha(\epsilon)}\int_{\partial B_\epsilon (0)} [\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)]\, dx\right|\leq \sup_{x\in \partial B_\epsilon(0)} |\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)|.
$$